# pull before push on my own forked branch?

Tags: git, github

I heard people are saying it's a good practice to always pull before push, that's true given we are working on the same master branch. But in my case, I forked the master branch so I have myforkedrepo/master which isn't the same with organisation/repo, so do I still need to pull before I push a new feature to myforkedrepo/master?

Answer (score 0):

1. If the remote repo has commits your local repo does not have, you need to pull first because git will not allow you to push.
2. If the remote repo did not have any commits you don't have, you can just push right away.

Generally you can just push at any point. Git will simply complain if you're missing commits. Just never use `-f` and you're safe.